# Fix oil stain on wooden parquet floor

Tags: floor, stain

I placed a bag that had something in it that was leaking vegetable oil on a wooden floor, and I now need to fix the problem. I've tried contacting multiple professionals, but it seems this is too small of a fix to warrant them even driving to my house, so I am left to fix it myself.

The question is: what solutions would I have to do it?

[image]

Comment: Add type of oil(vegetable, motor oil) and type of finish on the floor to your question.

Comment: added oil type, I don't know the type of finish - I presume lacquered

Comment: Try baby powder! Sprinkle on generously, the next day vacuum and wash with a mild soap and water, then dry with a soft cloth. It should be gone unless it has been there for a long time. Baby power works great on oil stains on clothing even some that have been through the wash cycle.

Comment: This site seems to have several suggestions https://www.howtocleanstuff.net/how-to-remove-oil-stains-from-wood/